# How to trigger an animation inside a listview item

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, storyboard, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to perform an animation on a listview item when i click on that item.

Here is the code i produced:

The storyboard:

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ShowPlaceDetailAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceDetaiGridN"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                From="0" To="200" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

And the listview:

```
        <ListView Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Places}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <controls:PlaceListItemControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PlaceListItemControlN"
                    PlaceName="{Binding PlaceName}"
                    Picture="{Binding Picture}"
                    Distance="{Binding Distance}"
                    Reviews="{Binding NumberOfReview}"
                    Stars="{Binding NumberOfStars}"
                    Category="{Binding Category}"
                    Height="100"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="5, 10, 5, 0">
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=PlaceViewN, Path=DataContext.PlaceTappedCommand}"
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowPlaceDetailAnimation}" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </controls:PlaceListItemControl>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Brown" x:Name="PlaceDetaiGridN">                            
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

You can consider the controls:PlaceListItemControl as a simple grid with a heigh of 150 or 200 whatever.

The problem with this approch is that when i click on a ListviewItem, the app crashes because of this line :

```
<media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowPlaceDetailAnimation}" />
```

Any idea on why and how to fix that issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'Storyboard' is defined in The Page's resources. ListViewItems are created in a different Context than the page, as they may exist multiple times. Therefore, you cannot address elements inside the 'DataTemplate'.

One possible solution would be to crate a 'UserControl' that hosts your Storyboard and the template content and then just place that control as your ItemTemplate.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Creating a comtrol looks like a good solution ;) i'll try that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `ListView` and override the `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` method in which you can create and start Storyboard animations on the `DependencyObject` reference you receive as an argument.